# Android App Links - exclude specific sub-directory

Tags: android, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, applinks, android-deep-link

I am using [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) to take users to a specific screen directly in my app. I am following the same approach as Rakuten, meaning the **last path segment(LPs)** of the URL is a valid domain, which lands users to a specific brand screen on my app.

```
https://www.rakuten.com/nike.com   (lps = nike.com)
https://www.rakuten.com/adidas.com   (lps = addidas.com)
https://www.rakuten.com/samsung.com   (lps = samsung.com)
```

Android Manifest Code

```
<data android:host="www.rakuten.com" android:scheme="https" android:pathPattern=".*..*"/>
```

The `pathPattern = ".*..*"` allows **any domain** in the URL to open inside my app. All of the below links open **Nike brand screen** in my app.

```
https://www.rakuten.com/dir1/nike.com
https://www.rakuten.com/dir1/dir2/nike.com
https://www.rakuten.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/nike.com
https://www.rakuten.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/nike.com
```

**CASE TO HANDLE:**

if any URL contains `/browser/` (meaning subdirectory name = `browser`), I want to open that URL in the browser and not inside my app.

```
https://www.rakuten.com/browser/nike.com (should open in browser and not in-app)
```

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: "Is there any possibility to do that?" -- not really. There is no "everything-except-for-X" syntax here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we can't exclude any certain url, since Android doesn't provide that option.

The best practice is to give as precise **pathPrefix** as possible.

```
<data android:scheme="https"
      android:host="www.rakuten.com"
      android:pathPrefix="/dir1/" />
```

So it will open https://www.rakuten.com/dir1/* links

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
<data android:host="www.rakuten.com/app" android:scheme="https" android:pathPattern=".*..*"/>
```

All routes that you want to open in app should live under [www.rakuten.com/app](http://www.rakuten.com/app)

All routes that you want to open in browser should live under [www.rakuten.com/](http://www.rakuten.com/)